# Friendly URL with ID to localized name

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

can you help me to make a htaccess and php function which should make friendly looking URLs like site.com/en/category/product

The site will be multilingual, therefore all category and product names will be localized.

The database will have records for each language - `product_id, category_id, name_en, category_en, name_de, category_de`, etc.

So a database record would be: `product_id - 05, category_id - 01, name_en - coffee05, category_en - coffee-and-tea, name_de - kaffee05, category_de - kaffee-und-tee`

So the URL `/product.php?lang=en&category=01&product=05` should become `/product/coffee-and-tea/coffee05` and for DE `/product/kaffee-und-tee/kaffee05`

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Did that code work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this the other day. Here's what I ended up using:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This sends all traffic to index.php with the variable url containing the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as `$_GET['url']`.

I then used the following function:

```
function url(){ 
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
            $routes = [];
            // get the URL from the base defined in the.htaccess file.
            // filter url
            # Example: www.yourdomain.com/example-page/hello/1/title/

            $url = filter_var(trim($_GET['url']),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
            // delete last / if it is there.
            $url = rtrim($url,'/');
            # Exampele change 1: $url = example-page/hello/1/title

            /*
             * Remove the - (dash) in the url : EX. example-page/hello. Classnames can't have the - (dash) so class is written as examplePage.
             * to call the function we need to remove the - (dash)
            */

            # Example change 2: $url = examplepage/hello/1/title
            $url = str_replace('-','', $url );
            // create array with all the url parts.
            # Example change 3: $url = ["examplepage","hello",1,"title"]
            $url = explode('/',$url);

            // add all array values to the var routes.
            foreach($url as $value){
                $routes[] = $value;
            }
        }
    return $routes;
}
```

This function returns an array from the `$_GET['url']`. From there, on index.php, you can `include` files based on the first item in the array, as well as assign values to the following values (or use their indexes) and decide what to do with the data from there.

For example:
If my page returns `example.org/products/12`,
I call the function:

```
$url = url();
$page = $url[0];
$id = $url[1];
include($page);
echo productData($id);
```

Comment: The url function was provided by @Jorn btw